# How do I redeem my coupon codes for Dragon's Nest?

Tags: dragons-nest

I have recently started playing this MMORPG called [Dragon's Nest](http://www.dragonnest.eu/), and through the usage of [Cherry Credits](http://www.cherrycredits.com/), I got myself a few in-game redeemable codes.

However, I have no idea how to redeem those codes. Even though the video below gives a detailed explanation on how to redeem them, the Cash Shop interface has changed and I can no longer find the 'redeem coupon' option he was showing me.

I have tried searching up on google or checking the forums, but to no avail. So, Does anyone know how to redeem coupons?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- At first visit this game Dashboard area.
- Then find out setting.
- After this process, you will see a redeem code entering option.
- And then put their valid coupon code.
- If all is OK. Now tap on the redeem button.